# How to create a editable data-table (with pagination) without using Angular material?

Tags: angular

I want to create an editable table in Angular but without using Angular material. The table should also have pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple html table with css styles
 1. have the angular reactive formArray 
 2. put the inputs into tables
 3. and you can use ng-bootstrap pagination
    https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/overview